# How to compute computational complexity of following nested loop

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, asymptotics

I need to compute the computational complexity in big-O notation of the following double nested loop,

Let S={1,2,...,N}, T={1,2,...,M} then we have summation of two variable J and K on these sets as

$$\sum_{m=1}^{M} \sum_{n=1}^{N} (J_{n,k}K_{n,k})_m \quad \forall k \in S$$

The variable *k* is defined for all values on set *S*

The issue here is that we do not sum on variable k which is troublesome to me.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous, it could be that $k$ is just fixed and you do the calculation for a single value of $k$, or it could be that you need to do the calculation for each possible value of $k$ and add them up.(Also, I don't understand why the upper limits are $S$ and $T$, should they be $N$ and $M$?) Also, you haven't said what $*$ and subscript $m$ mean.

Comment: Thanks Ian for valued correction. I have updated the post in regard of your comments. Please note that we need to compute J times K for every possible *k*.

Comment: OK. Now what's the subscript $m$ doing exactly? Why is $J_{n,k} K_{n,k}$ subscriptable, is it a vector or something?

Comment: No actually I want to compute  $J_{n,k} K_{n,k}$ and sum for every $m\in T$. For example, Let N=2, M=2 then I want to compute followings: $ ({J_{1,1} K_{1,1}+J_{1,2} K_{1,2}})_{m=1}+({J_{1,1} K_{1,1}+J_{1,2} K_{1,2}})_{m=2}$

Comment: So $J$ and $K$ are functions of $n,k$ and $m$? I still don't know what the subscript means. Would an equivalent way to write the problem be $\sum_{m=1}^M \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^K J_{n,k}(m) L_{n,k}(m)$ (where my $L$ replaces your $K$, since I needed to use $K$ for something else)?

Comment: correct but I actually want to get ride of third nested for loop otherwise it would require high computation. I guess for three nested for loops it would require $\frac{(J_{n,k}(m)L_{n,k}(m))^3-(J_{n,k}(m)L_{n,k}(m))}{3}$ Am I correct?